# How to convert char* filename to string?

Tags: string, visual-c++, visual-studio-2008

How can i convert a char* filename to a string type in C++ .
I'm working on file handles .One instance is of process and other one is a filename .
For comparison purpose i need to convert both to String Type.

```
if(_stricmp(pEntry32.szExefile,filename) ==0)
{ //HANDLE stuff
}
```

this module wOrks fine on DEV C++ but not on VS 2008 .

Comment: shouldn't the [`c_str`/`data` method](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str) of the C++ `String` class provide a C compatible char array that you could use ?

Answer (score 1):

The `std::string` class has a constructor that takes a c string.

```
std::string process_str = std::string(pEntry32.szExefile);
std::string filename_str = std::string(filename);
```